# Powershell - многострочная переменная

Tags: json, powershell

День добрый.
Требуется отправить JSON запрос на определенный API, тело запроса формируется следующим образом:

```
$MsgBody = 
@'
{
    "message": {
       "uid": "1520",
       "mesg": "Test mail",
      }
    }
'@
```

Не могу найти описание синтаксиса - как подставить в uid определенную переменную?
Формат

```
    "message": {
       "uid": $MyTExt,
```

не подходит.
Каким образом обычно формируется многострочное тело JSON запроса, если в него необходимо заключать значения своих переменных?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят, необходимо было использовать двойные кавычки при использовании @" (вместо @') :

```
$MsgBody = 
@"
{
    "message": {
       "uid": "$MyText",
       "mesg": "Test mail",
      }
    }
"@
```